# Vue cannot find module image location

Tags: vue.js, module, src

I'm having a problem with my project not finding the path to my png images. I know the path is correct because if I use a basic hard coded src="../assets/die1.png", it works fine. The problem is I need them to changed based on other data.

I keep getting the error: Cannot find module '../assets/die1.png'

COMPONENT:

```
<template>
  <div class="DiceComponent col-3 bg-primary">
    <img v-if="die.output != ''" :src="require(die.output)" alt="error loading image" />
  </div>
</template>
```

NOTE: die.output == "../assets/die1.png" and this is confirmed in the Vue devtool.

[EDIT: This is currently what I get when it tries to load.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1FaU.jpg)

Comment: What is `require` ?

Comment: is die.output ===  "../assets/die1.png"' ?

Comment: I've had to use require on other projects' images. Not entirely sure why, but I read it has something to do with how Vue compiles into vanilla JS

Comment: and yes Tony, they're exactly the same

Comment: Please post more code so that you can receive help. The file structure will be nice to have. Also, the `data` property with the `die` object( I am assuming `die` is one of them). If the `die` object is not in the `data` property, please share where you get the `die` object from.

Comment: Feel free to check it all out here 

https://github.com/Kevinclane/DieRoller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am getting some error in your store functions that I can solve now so I focused on the image question. As you are working with static files, I've moved them to public folder and have made a simple rollDice function:

```
rollDice() {
   let rng = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
   this.diceTemp = `./die${rng+1}.png`
},
```

then:

```
<Die :die="diceTemp" />
```

inside the component:

```
<img :src="die" />
```

and this works fine! Somethings to consider:

- If you are using stores you can use die values inside your Die component and avoid using nested values (die.output) props ([vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html))

Comment: I tried that as well but I get the same error.

The full error code is:

Error: Cannot find module ' ../assets/die2.png'
    at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./src/components sync recursive (app.js:1148), <anonymous>:2:10)
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules/.cache/vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"200ee25a-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/DiceComponent.vue?

Comment: vue&type=template&id=1928e616& (app.js:998), <anonymous>:11:79)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4540)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2784)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3138)
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3215)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2977)
    at Array.eval (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1833)
    at MessagePort.flushCallbacks (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1754)

Comment: updated component template

```
<template>
  <div class="DiceComponent col-3 bg-primary">
    <img v-if="die.output != ''" :src="die.output" alt="error loading image" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: updated with an image and everything seems to work fine to me

Comment: The line that's highlighted there and shows up directly under the roll button is the hardcoded die image. Does it work if you select a number of dice then hit roll? If you want the Vue dev tool, you can see that each component updates the die.output correctly on each roll, but it doesn't display the image. I did more research and found that Vue isn't set up to take .png files and you need webpacks. not entirely sure if I have those set up or not. I know I have some, not sure if I have the right ones or if they're configured correctly.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't saw an error on console and thought that was the dice rendered.  I've edited again my answer and solved your images problem but maybe you have a store problem too

Comment: Seems to be working now, thanks! I am curious why it doesn't like the simple address push into the template.

Answer (score 1):

For readability you can change your **output** variable to:

```
die.output == require('../assets/die1.png')
```

or

```
die.output == require('@/assets/die1.png')
```

And then

```
<template>
  <div ...>
    <img ... :src="die.output" ... />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace what you have now with

```html
<template>
  <div ...>
    <img ... :src="require(`${die.output}`)" ... />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It still causes the error. Removing the require part stops the errors, but does trigger the alt mesage.

Answer (score 0):

It was hard but I found a way

try this:

```
let imgName = "logo-blue.svg";

getLogo(imgName) {
const partName = imgName.split("logo-")[1];
return require("../img/logo-" + partName);
}
```

I don't know why, but if you do `return require("../img/" + imgName);` it doesn't work, just with the split it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem too; I fixed that with the following solution:

```
<img :src="srcComputed" />

computed: {
  srcComputed() {
     return require(`@/assets/images/${this.srcProps}`);
  },
},
```

Note: I am using a component with a Props, `srcProps`.