# Getting a Vue Error: Cannot find module for image for dynamic image

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, src

I looked at [Vue cannot find module image location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63238865/vue-cannot-find-module-image-location) and couldn't figure out a solution.

in my code when I hard code it

```
:src="require('@/assets/featured/pizzaOne.jpeg')"
```

I get the image.
But when I try

```
:src="require(`${item.img}`)"
```

I get Error: Cannot find module '@/assets/featured/pizzaOne.jpeg'
Not sure why and how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

If you can change `item.img` to just name `pizzaOne.jpeg`, then in method:

```
methods: {
  getImgUrl: function (img) { 
     return require('@/assets/featured/' + img);
  }
}
```

end in template:

```
<img :src="getImgUrl(item.img)" />
```

Comment: Great solution! It works but you need to make sure the method name `getImgUrl` matches the one used in the <img> tag. So it's either `getImgUrl` or  `getImage`, or anything you fancy really as long as the names matching.